# CMake configuration equivalent of GCC options

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker

Compiling my C++ `SDL2` project with a `g++` using `MinGW-w64` on Windows 10 is quite simple with the following command:
`g++ main.c -o game.exe -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`
But I can't seem to create an equivalent configuration with `CMake`.

This is how my `CMakeList.txt` file looks like (generated by CLion):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(cfirst)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(cfirst ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

This fails compilation, citing multiple *"undefined references"*, including an *"undefined reference to `WinMain@16'"*, which I assume is caused by incorrectly compiling as 64bit.
This is identical to what happens if I omit the `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2` options when using `g++` directly.
How would I go about adding equivalent configuration to the `CMakeList.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If linker can find the libs, this should work:

```
target_link_libraries(cfirst PRIVATE mingw32 SDL2main SDL2)
```